# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException error

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, web-applications, tomcat7

I've just reconfigured my Eclipse IDE.

And when I run my web application, I got this error

It seems that I miss [this Jar](http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/com.sun.istack.localization.Localizable), I placed it in my **lib folder of my Dynamic Web Application** but it doesn't work.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.istack.localization.Localizable
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:208)
    com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:112)
    javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Unknown Source)
    com.bh.services.client.ServiceService.<init>(ServiceService.java:41)
    com.bh.servlets.Connexion.doPost(Connexion.java:35)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
```

**IDE:** Eclipse.
**Local server:** Tomcat 7.

Any help please?

Comment: Are you using any IDE to build the application? Does it compile there?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse, yes it does. The problem appears when I'm trying to navigate on my web application

Comment: Try adding some other .jar to the lib folder and see if it works. Then you'll know if it's a Tomcat problem or a problem with that specific .jar.

Answer (score 0):

After placing the jar file in the lib folder of your web-app, you also need to add that jar file to your 'Build Path'.
To check if the jar file is in your projects build path, in your project explorer window go to 'Java Resources' there should be two more menu items under it : 1.src and 2.Libraries.
check under Libraries if the jar file you added exists there or not.
If it doesn't exists, then in the lib folder where you actually stored the jar file, just right click on it then in the menu select Build Path and then 'Add to Build Path'.
Just it, you are done then.